# Talend : How to fix the code of method is exceeding the 65535 byte limit

Tags: etl, talend

I have a set of 5 tables that have 2 millions rows and 450 columns approximately

My job look like this :

```
tDBInput 1 ---tMap-----

tDBInput 1 ---tMap-----

tDBInput 1 ---tMap---tUnite---tDBOutput

tDBInput 1 ---tMap-----

tDBInput 1 ---tMap-----
```

It's my 5 tables tables that I'm trying to union, with the tMap where I'm adding an Id to trace which table date come from + reduce number of columns (from 450 to 20)
Then I unite the 5 in one tUnite that load a table in Truncate - Insert mode

I'm trying to make it work but always have the same error which is "The code of method tDBInput-10Process is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use only 20 of 450 columns, you could select only those columns in each of your tDBInput, instead of extracting all columns and filtering them in tMap.

Comment: [https://community.talend.com/s/article/Exceeding-the-Java-bytes-limit-1Z1UZ?language=en_US][1]

follow this link, you need to minimize the column numbers or break your job in multiple subjobs.